# How do I return a table of rows from a list in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to generate rows given a list of values in postgresql. For example, if I have the values `1, 2, 5, 10, 30, 180`, I would like to return:

```
num
----
1
2
5
10
30
180
```

I've been trying to use the VALUES function, but haven't had any luck. Here's an example of a failed atttempt:

```
SELECT num
FROM
VALUES (1, 2, 5, 10, 30, 180) as num
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`values (1, 2, 5, 10, 30, 180)` returns a **single** row with 6 columns.

But you want six *rows* with one column:

```
SELECT num
FROM (
   VALUES (1), (2), (5), (10), (30), (180) 
) as t(num)
```

`as t(num)` assigns an alias to the derived table (the `values` part) which is named `t` and has a single column `num`.

Using the table alias in the select list returns a record, not a column.